# Android MainActivity and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, instance

I have a problem when trying to reach objects from different classes. I'm on an android project an I've done a socketconnection from my MainActivity class that extends Activity. Then I've made another class called SmsReceiver that extends BroadcastReceiver so I can get messages that are sent to my phone (emulator). Now I need the SmsReceiver class to use the outputstream object from the MainActivity class but I don't know how to reach it. I cannot make a new instance of MainActivity.

Can I somehow send the outputstream object to the SmsReceiver class?
I hope some of you got some tips, thanks in advance!

---

Ok now I've gone for the interface solution but I'm stuck again!

Here are my classes:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MainInterface
{

try {
                            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                            in = new BufferedReader(new                                InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            System.err.println("Error in creating Streams:" +   ex.toString());
                            return;
                        }

public PrintWriter getOutputStream() {
        return out;
    }
}
```

**MainInterface:**

```
public interface MainInterface {
    public PrintWriter getOutputStream();
}
```

**SmsReceiver:**

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    MainInterface mainInterface = new MainActivity();  ///// <------
    PrintWriter out;  //// <--------

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mainInterface.getOutputStream(); ////// <------------
        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {
            if(bundle != null){

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for(int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++){
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                    out.println("senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                    out.flush(); /// these two lines
                }
              }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
        }
    }

}
```

For some reason the PrintWriter that I get through the interface is *null*, and the inputstream on the desktop (which is the program that should receive the message when doing **out.println()**) doesn't even get the message, it's just blocked at **in.readLine()**. 
Am I instantiating the interface the wrong way or what's going on?

The logcat error print is:
**09-15 14:13:55.880: E/SmsReceiver(1361): Exception smsReceiverjava.lang.NullPointerException**

Comment: usually you would instantiate and register your Broadcast receiver in your activity.

Comment: You mean like not creating a separate class for the broadcastreceiver?

Comment: you can, but instantiate it in the Activity, e.g. MyBroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();

Comment: I tried that before asking here. It just made my app crash. I think it instantiates MyBroadcastReceiver when running MainActivity, and then when I instantiate it by code it makes a duplicate or something and crashes.

Comment: i don't think this is the reason for crashing your app, can you paste the logcat error ?

Comment: I'm not at home right now but I can do that tomorrow!

Comment: I've now tried initiating SmsReceiver (which extends BroadcastReceiver) again in the MainActivity class, and sending the outputstream object as a parameter to the constructor. When receiving a message and trying to send it over the outputstream object I get the same error in the logcat as I wrote in my updated question. The error is: "09-15 14:53:14.740: E/SmsReceiver(1445): Exception smsReceiverjava.lang.NullPointerException"

Answer (score 0):

You must be setting an intent to BroadcastReceiver class in your MainActivity, why are you not sending the data using the intent of this BroadcastReceiver, it will be much easier than the approach I asked earlier before seeing your code.

The data you will receive in intent of broadcast receiver, please check if this solution works.
But, you need to work out on a way to send a PrintWriter object through intent.

Another solution can be to use and observer and subscriber pattern, you can find multiple examples on net for same.

Comment: i think he needs the Broadcast receiver to send data through the output stream ... and how would the broadcast receiver get the instance of the activity ? I don't think this is a good solution

Comment: @Su-AuHwang Actually I don't really need an instance of the activity, I just need the outputstream. This might actually work, I'll try it tomorrow when I'm on my computer!

Comment: @Su-AuHwang - Here requirement is only for the output stream object, instance of main activity was needed to access outputstream object, when the solution is coming without accessing the object, this solution will perfectly work. :)

Comment: if you don't actually need an activity, then you should try out a service.

Comment: Please check my edit if you have time!
@Su-AuHwang you too please

Comment: I read about sending data using the intent of the BroadcastReceiver but it wouldn't work for objects like you said. I also read about making objects parcable or serializable but that wouldn't work for complex objects like a PrintWriter either. My final solution was to make my PrintWriter object public and static which makes it reachable from "MyBroadcastReceiver" class (SmsReceiver) by typing MainActivity.out. Do you think this solution is bad?